# "No such file: 'requirements.txt' error" while installing Quartz module

Tags: python, pip, quartz

When I try to install Quartz on my system using `pip install Quartz`, I face with the following error. I use Mac OSX with Anaconda. Any help is appreciated.

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/sb/llj7h5px227_5b0__3v0sw5r0000gn/T/pip-build-qf8ezbu5/Quartz/setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    install_requires=read_dependencies("requirements.txt"),
  File "/private/var/folders/sb/llj7h5px227_5b0__3v0sw5r0000gn/T/pip-build-qf8ezbu5/Quartz/setup.py", line 7, in read_dependencies
    with open(req_file) as req:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Comment: Reported issue [here](https://github.com/vladcalin/quartz/issues/1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the `setup.py` of the package, so I tried the following:

1. Run: `pip download quartz`.
2. Find the downloaded `quartz-0.0.1.dev0.tar.gz`.
3. Extract and in `setup.py` find the following line

   ```
   install_requires=read_dependencies(“requirements.txt")
   ```

   and change it to:

   ```
   install_requires=read_dependencies("quartz.egg-info/requires.txt")
   ```
4. Run: `pip install -e /path/to/quartz-0.0.1.dev0`.

Setup should be completed w/o errors.

Alternatively try this (which fixes ImportError: No module named 'Quartz' when installing `pyautogui` I encountered when installing `pyautogui`):

1. `pip install pyobjc-core`
2. `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

Comment: Thanks, bam. I tried your first solution and it worked. But now, when I want to install `pyautogui` I get the same error that `ImportError: No module named 'Quartz'`. In addition, when I try again `pip install Quartz` it says that `Requirement already satisfied`! Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Try this: - `pip install pyobjc-core`
- `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

Comment: Hi can you please help me installing pyautogui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135927/getting-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-error-while-installing-pyaut

Answer (score 5):

This is the bug of [`quartz` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quartz) which is missing `requirements.txt` file in `MANIFEST.in` as per [author's comment on GitHub issue](https://github.com/vladcalin/quartz/issues/1#issuecomment-304782264), therefore it's not shipped with the sources. This won't be fixed anytime soon as it's currently abandoned due to poor architectural design.

So you can either:

- Manually download sources from [GitHub](https://github.com/vladcalin/quartz) and run the `setup.py` from there to install `quartz` package.
- Download package by `pip download quartz`, and place the missing [`requirements.txt` file](https://github.com/vladcalin/quartz/blob/master/requirements.txt) from GitHub into extracted sources, and run the install.
- Or follow steps provided in [@bam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736220/55075).

There is ongoing work on new version and it will be published soon when it is ready.